# why is it that you can append to a list with the '+=' operator but not with the '+' operator?

Tags: python, list, operators

the codes below are attempting to append an item to a list

this works well!

```
word = []
word += "e"
print (word)
```

this returns error

```
word = []
word = word + "e"
print (word)
```

[1st code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7guxH.png)
[2nd code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCCaW.png)

i thought  both would either bring an error or both should work